# Please help me to deploy Docker app onto heroku, Steps in the documentation don't work?

Tags: heroku

As you can see in the screenshot below, I am following the commands according to the heroku documentation to deploy Docker app. Yet I keep getting the response saying

> No Images to push

[image]

I am a heroku newbie, so please help me to find out what I have done wrong!

Answer (score 0):

add -a  to your heroku  command

Comment: you can see that i have put "--app" to the command, are they not same ?

adding -a to the command gives the following error.

 ›   Error: Flag --app expects a value

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the docker image name that you are pushing. i.e. `~/heroku/bin/heroku container:push web --app code--tube`

note: if your project isn't a web application then give the docker image the correct process type, i.e. (web, worker, image, etc)

As a side note, it isn't a good idea to give read, write, execute permissions to all users. You should only give permissions to those who need it. Giving too many permissions can also cause problems in some applications or files that will make things stop working.